# \multicolumn error in texmaker

Tags: tables, paragraphs, texmaker, eps

The code below gives me the following error: `! Paragraph ended before \multicolumn was complete.`

I tried several times but I cannot find what I did wrong. The exact same table works perfectly fine in MikTeX, but I am using TeXmaker now and it does not work. Is there a special package that I should import?

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{J48PerClass.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{PARTCM.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{SVMCM.eps} \\
\small{(a) J48} & \small{(b) PART} & \small{(c) SVM} \\
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{J48PCM.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{PARTPCM.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{MLPCM.eps} \\
\small{(d) J48 pruned} & \small{(e) PART pruned} & \small{(f) MLP} \\
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{NBCM.eps}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{

\raisebox{2.2cm}{\footnotesize{
\begin{tabular} {|l|l|}
\hline
  a = SQL injection              &l = Static \\
  b = Denial of Service          &m = Other attack\\
  c = Spam on Wiki               &n = Password cracking on Wiki \\  
  d = Spam on Blog               &o = Spam on Wiki  \\
  e = Password cracking on Blog  &p = Wiki  \\
  f = Other vulnerability scan   &q = Blog \& Wiki  \\
  g = DFind                      &r = Blog  \\
  h = Other fingerprinting       &s = Spam on Blog  \\
  i = (XSS) Cross site scripting & \\
  j = (RFI) Remote file inclusion  & \\
  k = Static \& Blog \& & \\
  \ \ \ \ \ Wiki        & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }}}
 \\

\small{(g) NB} & & \\

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: First of all, [welcome to TeX.SE!!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I would, as an aside, take a look at [this popular question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339) and become familiar with the difference between your editor and your compiler.  Very, *very* rarely does your choice of editor make a difference in how your code compiles.

Answer (score 2):

The following line

```
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{NBCM.eps}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{
```

produces an error, because is followed by an empty line, which means a new paragraph for TeX.

Answer (score 2):

While blank lines are generally allowed in a `tabular` environment, they aren't inside a `\multicolumn`.

You also have some spurious spaces, I marked them with `<-- here` and protected the end-of-lines with a `%`

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{J48PerClass.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{PARTCM.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{SVMCM.eps} \\
\small{(a) J48} & \small{(b) PART} & \small{(c) SVM} \\
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{J48PCM.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{PARTPCM.eps} &
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{MLPCM.eps} \\
\small{(d) J48 pruned} & \small{(e) PART pruned} & \small{(f) MLP} \\
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{NBCM.eps}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{% <-- here
\raisebox{2.2cm}{\footnotesize{% <-- here
\begin{tabular} {|l|l|}
\hline
  a = SQL injection              &l = Static \\
  b = Denial of Service          &m = Other attack\\
  c = Spam on Wiki               &n = Password cracking on Wiki \\  
  d = Spam on Blog               &o = Spam on Wiki  \\
  e = Password cracking on Blog  &p = Wiki  \\
  f = Other vulnerability scan   &q = Blog \& Wiki  \\
  g = DFind                      &r = Blog  \\
  h = Other fingerprinting       &s = Spam on Blog  \\
  i = (XSS) Cross site scripting & \\
  j = (RFI) Remote file inclusion  & \\
  k = Static \& Blog \& & \\
  \ \ \ \ \ Wiki        & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}% <-- here
  }}}
 \\

\small{(g) NB} & & \\

\end{tabular}
```